# Resuming canceled ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, download, asihttprequest

Is it possible to resume canceled download in ASIHTTPRequest? I download file with this code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.download",fileName]]];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestDidFailed:)];
[request setDidStartSelector:@selector(requestDidStarted:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestDidFinished:)];
[request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:path];
[request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

And cancel with this code:

```
[request cancel];
```

How to resume this download if it's possible? Or how to pause requests correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This site might help, scroll down to the Resuming interrupted downloads section.  http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: I know about this link. I didn't find there how to resume canceled download. Only resuming interrupted.